# MongoDB Map/Reduce only working in inline-mode

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I wrote map/reduce/finalize function which are working fine during my tests with the out: {inline: true} option.
But if I try to save the result in a collection using out: {replace: 'test'} (or merge, ..) it won't show me the same result.

Does anyone has a clue, what I am doing wrong?

Thx

Inline:

```
db.runCommand({mapreduce: 'source', map: map_deliverstat, reduce: reduce_deliverstat, finalize: finalize_deliverstat, out: {inline:1}})

{
"_id": {
    "date": ISODate("2012-03-13T00:00:00Z"),
    "customerid": 469
},
"value": {
    "date": ISODate("2012-03-13T00:00:00Z"),
    "customerid": NumberLong(469),
    "sum": 294,
    "nomarker": 42,
    "marker": 252,
    "product1": 34,
    "product2": 22,
    "product3": 20,
    "product4": 19,
    "product5": 16
}
}
```

Replace:

```
db.runCommand({mapreduce: 'source', map: map_deliverstat, reduce: reduce_deliverstat, out: {replace: 'test'}, finalize: finalize_deliverstat})

{
"_id": {
    "date": ISODate("2012-03-13T00:00:00Z"),
    "customerid": 469
},
"value": {
    "date": ISODate("2012-03-13T00:00:00Z"),
    "customerid": NumberLong(469),
    "sum": 2,
    "nomarker": 0,
    "marker": 2,
    "product1": 0,
    "product2": 0,
    "product3": 0,
    "product4": 0,
    "product5": 0
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another way of running map reduce, modify as per your need and see if this works for you

The following query counts the number of customers group by state

```
map = function() {
 emit({state: this.CustomerState}, {count:1})
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
  var count = 0;

  values.forEach(function(v) {
    count += v['count'];
  });

  return {state: key,count: count};
}
db.createCollection('map_temp')
db.customer_info.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:'map_temp'})
```

You will have the result saved in `map_temp` collection

Comment: the mapreduce still produces the same, different output. So no effect there. I'm trying a different mongo version - because on my production environment it works :-S